# get_terms in a taxonomy template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, archive-template

I've two custom taxonomies, and two template archives:
taxonomy-brand.php and taxonomy-producer.php

If I insert `$terms = get_terms('brand');` in the taxonomy-producer.php
I can't get terms for the taxonomy `brand`.
If I write something like `echo $terms->slug;`, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) returns array of terms and not only one term, so you can't do `$terms->slug`, because it makes no sense at all...

If you want to display all terms, you'll have to loop through them:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'brand',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if ( ! is_wp_error($terms) ) {  // it can return WP_Error
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->slug;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm searching for this, in my newbie's try!